# MVC Exception Handling Display Custom View Not Working in IE Only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, exception

I'm working with MVC 3 and have encountered a strange error. I have customErrors='On' and the standard Error.cshtml view in the Shared Views folder. I'm throwing a deliberate exception to test this.

In FireFox my view is displayed with the custom error message. However, in IE the view is not displayed and instead I see a generic HTTP 500 Internal Server Error Page - The website cannot display the page displayed.

Does anyone know why this works in FireFox but not IE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet explorer has an option (checked by default) to hide 50x errors. It's called "Show friendly HTTP error messages", and you can uncheck it by going to "Internet Options" > "Advanced". When checked, IE shows the page you are seeing, instead of the one returned by the server.

Apparently, you can override this behaviour if the content returned by the server is big enough (!!), as you can see in the following document by MS (Method 2):
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807/en-us

Comment: Good spot ! I added a few more lines to my error message and it's now being displayed in IE.

Comment: +1 for the override based on string length in IE! Fixed my issue.